# Count all words in a string that start with a capital letter

Tags: java, string, character

I study Java at university and I need to Write a static **int countCapitals(String s)** method that returns how many words in the string s start with a capital letter.

The uppercase letter is a character (Character) of the UPPERCASE_LETTER type or the TITLE CASE_LETTER type. A word is a sequence of letters or numbers separated by one or more whitespaces, characters, symbols, or punctuation marks.

New.countCapitals("Hello,My dear friends!Here—Words beginning with Ćapital ŁeTtErS") == 6

I'm allowed to use only methods in String and Character classes.(no RegEx)

```java
public class New {
    static int countCapitals(String s) {
        int c = 0;
        if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) == true
                || Character.isTitleCase(s.charAt(0)) == true) {
            c++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) == false
                    && Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i + 1)) == true) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i + 1)) == true
                        || Character.isTitleCase(s.charAt(i + 1)) == true) {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

This is my code, but it doesn't work on some tests. Tests are closed, so I don't know on which ones. Could you tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Hint: you dont need other people to approach such problems. Instead: step back and think up YOUR OWN tests. Ask yourself about "normal cases", and "edge cases" and so on. And: consider to NOT use single char variable names. If at all, use those for loop index. But other names should tell the reader what the variable is about. c, s ... tells the reader nothing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "tests are closed", how are you exercising your code to see whether it's performing as you expected?  The simplest approach is to create another test class that runs your code against the test case string you show at the top of your post.  Strip all the code and just return zero from your method and run test case - it will be wrong of course.  But now you have a repeatable test, implement your algorithm and repeat until you get it right.  Otherwise you're just guessing.

Comment: @stridecolossus - I think the OP is referring to the tests run by the instructor, in that the students can't see the test cases that will be thrown at it when the code is run, when the app is submitted.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yeah assumed something like that, hence suggestion to create a test case.

Comment: If you use String#split() to break your sentence into words, all you need to do is to check the first character of each word. Then all you need to do is to iterate through the array and check if ``word.charAt(0)`` fits your definition of an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's built-in regex package is the way I'd go:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordsStartingWithCapitalLetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test 1 -- simple sentence
        String s = "The Quick Brown Fox jumps over the lazy Dog";
        System.out.println("\ninput string: " + s);
        System.out.println("capitalized words:" + getCountOfWordsWithInitialCap(s));

        // Test 2 -- punctuation and newlines
        s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\n"
        + "incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation\n"
        + "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit\n"
        + "in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat\n"
        + "non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
        System.out.println("\ninput string: " + s);
        System.out.println("capitalized words:" + getCountOfWordsWithInitialCap(s));

        // Test 3 -- Scottish sirnames and hyphens
        s = "The quick brown MacGavin jumps over the lazy MacGowan-dog";
        System.out.println("\ninput string: " + s);
        System.out.println("capitalized words:" + getCountOfWordsWithInitialCap(s));
    }

    private static final Pattern WORD_WITH_CAP_REGEX = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][-A-Za-z]*)");

    private static int getCountOfWordsWithInitialCap(String s) {
         int count = 0;
         Matcher matcher = WORD_WITH_CAP_REGEX.matcher(s);
         while(matcher.find()) {
            count++;
            String capitalizedWord = matcher.group(1);
            System.out.println("\t"+count+" : "+capitalizedWord);   // remove if you don't want to see the matches
         }
         return count;
    }
}
```